# What constitutes as an empty space?

Tags: stardew-valley

When growing fruit trees, the informative text under it states that the surrounding 8 tiles must be empty. Naturally, this brings me to the question. "What constitutes as empty?"

After planting my fruit trees, often times naturally spawning entities such as rock and grass will spawn around the fruit trees. Afraid that this might hinder the growth of my fruit trees, I surrounded my trees with "wooden flooring" bought from Robin's store. It will also add to the aesthetic appeal of the place. This led me to wonder if the wooden flooring itself will slow down the growth of the fruit trees.

I checked the wiki and it stated that:

> Fruit trees can only be planted in a clear 3x3 area. They are planted
>   directly into untilled ground. The 3x3 area around a fruit tree
>   sapling must remain clear and untilled or its development will be
>   hindered.

So it understand that the ground should remain untilled. However, nothing is mentioned about the possible effects of rocks and the aforementioned wooden flooring.

**Therefore, before I continue on, I would like to know what counts as empty.**

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you place yourself is not counted as empty space.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? What about grass, since I could place it myself or it could grow there?

Comment: @Studoku [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/4bhkso/psa_path_tiles_will_prevent_fruit_trees_from/) and my own experience. You can plant trees next to occupied space, but they won't grow.